# Understanding the practical benefits of Durable Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I've read a few articles about Azure Durable Functions but for whatever reason the benefit still hasn't quite landed with me.

One article provides a real world example:

> Let’s say you’re selling airline tickets. You can imagine that as a
> person buys a ticket, we need to:
>
> Check for the availability of the ticket.
> Make a request to get the seat map.
> Get their mileage points if they’re a loyalty member. Give them a mobile notification if the payment comes through and they have an app
> installed

I appreciate this is a workflow with multiple asynchronous awaits, but what's the issue with a standard Azure Function which simply places the API calls and awaits the results before continuing?

It would be great to understand how Durable Functions improve the above example compared to Standard Functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find (maybe you already did) some scenarios examples on MS pages already:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup?tabs=csharp#scenario-overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-monitor?tabs=csharp#scenario-overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-monitor-python#scenario-overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-phone-verification?tabs=csharp#scenario-overview

From own experience we used Durable Functions mostly for the functionality to start over from the point where e.g. function (one of its stages) failed. With this we can like "continue" to complete whole chain only referring to same entity in durable functions. With non-durable function this could also be achieved, of course, but somehow needed additional services like service bus.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to understand the benefit of the first one - why do they create a separate E2_GetFileList function given that it can't scale? Also they say a queue would be needed for regular functions but I'm not sure I see why? A regular function can fan out to other functions and wait for all to come back.